# Object.create() bug?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function create_RowsEditor(tableId, rowTmplId) {
  rowsEditor = Object.create(null, {
    'XtableId': tableId,
    'XrowTmplId': rowTmplId
  });
  return rowsEditor;
}

$(function() {
  var rowsEditor = create_RowsEditor('come', 'tmpl_row');
});
```

Error: TypeError: value is not a non-null object

Where is the error?

Comment: @JoeEnos True, but if you read the docs, it should only throw a `TypeError` if the first parameter is not `null` and not an `Object`

Comment: @Ian Yep, I jumped the gun a bit, deleted my comment. Null is acceptable as the first parameter.

Comment: @JoeEnos It was my immediate thought too...like "why pass `null`"? But then I looked it up :)

Comment: As a matter of propriety, it's better to have your question make the assumption that your own code is bugged, and not the native code... that is unless you can provide the text of the specified behavior, and an example of non-compliance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot pass an arbitrary object as second parameter, it has to be an object of *property descriptors*. For example:

```
rowsEditor = Object.create(null, {
  'XtableId': {
      value: tableId
  },
  'XrowTmplId': {
      value: rowTmplId
  }
});
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

> If specified and not undefined, an object whose enumerable own properties (that is, those properties defined upon itself and not enumerable properties along its prototype chain) specify property descriptors to be added to the newly-created object, with the corresponding property names. These properties correspond to the second argument of [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

Detailed information about the structure of property descriptors can be found in the [`Object.defineProperty` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). As shown in the code above, the `value` property specifies the value of the property.

Comment: You have to add a value key for every property? That is nuts. Is there an easier way to override or extend a superclass?