# Extending (inherit) class (or object ) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, intern, ui-testing

I'm working on a UI automation project where i want to extend one page object from another page object. I googled for the way to achieve this but couldn't find exactly what i am searching for. 
Basically i have a code setup something like this.

BasePage.js

```
    define([],
         function () {

            function BasePage(remote) {
             this.remote = remote;

            }

            BasePage.prototype = {
              constructor: BasePage,
             // common methods to interact with page

             commonMethodToIntreactWithPage : function{
               return doSomething;
             }
    };

    return BasePage;
});
```

LoginPage.js

```
    define([],
         function () {

            function LoginPage(remote) {
             this.remote = remote;

            }

            LoginPage.prototype = {
              constructor: BasePage,
             // Login Page related Methods

             loginPageRelatedMethod: function{
               return doSomething;
             }
    };

    return LoginPage;
});
```

I want to inherit the method of `BasePage` in `LoginPage` by just doing this:

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage(remote);
loginPage.commonMethodToIntreactWithPage();
```

Just for information I'm using `Intern.js` for testing.

Comment: you could try `LoginPage.prototype = new BasePage()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define something like this. The first row will create a new object with the properties and methods, which are in `BasePage.prototype` and set the prototype reference to this, so every `LoginPage` object will have those properties and objects. After all I add all specific data which is related only to `LoginPage` (`loginPageRelatedMethod`). And also it is important to set the proper `constructor`.

```
LoginPage.prototype = Object.create(BasePage.prototype);

LoginPage.prototype.constructor = LoginPage;

LoginPage.prototype.loginPageRelatedMethod = function(){
    return doSomething;
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
function LoginPage(remote) {
   BasePage.call(this, remote);
}
```

Example

```js
function BasePage(remote) {
   this.remote = remote;
}

BasePage.prototype = {
   constructor: BasePage,    
   commonMethodToIntreactWithPage : function() {
      return 'From Base Page';
   }
};

function LoginPage(remote) {
   BasePage.call(this, remote);
}

LoginPage.prototype = Object.create(BasePage.prototype);

LoginPage.prototype.constructor = LoginPage;

LoginPage.prototype.loginPageRelatedMethod = function () {
   return 'From Login Page';
}

var loginPage = new LoginPage('Test');
console.log(loginPage.commonMethodToIntreactWithPage());
```

Comment: Please note that `Object.create` second argument can't  be any object, it has to be an object of _property descriptors_ and `BasePage.prototype` isn't such object. Please check this SO answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408350/object-create-bug

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz Sorry, I misstyped something, the first parameter should be `BasePage.prototype`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan all this should be incuded in `LoginPage.js` ??

Comment: Yes, if you have access to `BasePage` there

Comment: How can i pass the argument to the constructor of  `BaseTest` ?

Comment: So you need to call it in the LoginPage, like `BasePage.call(this,/* params */)`

Comment: is it inside of the constructor of `LofinPage` as  `BasePage.call(this,remote) ?`

Comment: but when i did `loginPage.commonMethodToIntreactWithPage()` it gives    'loginPage.commonMethodToIntreactWithPage  is not a function' is not a function

Comment: @CodeBloded see the example in the answer and look what you did wrong